# DIV doesn't place at top of cell

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-tables

I have a simple [table like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Rf8Hz/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <link href="Theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="Calendar">
        <div>   
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="headerLeft">yyyyyy</div>
                    <div class="headerRight">xxxxxx</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="headerLeft">yyyyyy</div>
                    <div class="headerRight">xxxxxx</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div>asfs</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.Calendar
{
    display:table;
    width:500px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.Calendar > div
{
    display:table-row;
}
.Calendar > div > div
{
    display:table-cell;
    height:70px;
    border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
}

.headerRight
{
    float:right;
}
.headerLeft
{
    float:left;
}
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Why is the div ("yyy xxx") in first cell not place at the top? Please let me now if I am doing something wrong or missing something which needs to be added. I tested on Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add `vertical-align: top;` to the `.Calendar > div > div` css.
That is assuming you want all of the cells to have their content aligned to the `top` instead of the default `middle`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very inelegant, but all you have to do is reverse the order of your divs, so put the .headerRight div in FRONT of the .headerLeft div, in your HTML

Comment: Is this what your code now looks like?

                <div>
                    <div class="headerRight">xxxxxx</div>
                    <div class="headerLeft">yyyyyy</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

Answer (score 0):

Add  `vertical-align:top;` to the css `.Calendar > div > div`

```
 .Calendar > div > div
{
    vertical-align:top;
    display:table-cell;
    height:70px;
    border: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
}
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rf8Hz/3/)